# P-Value from Watson.test

Tags: r, statistical-significance, circular-statistics

I am using the circular package to evaluate if my circular data is uniform or not.
The package PDF can be found here -> https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circular/circular.pdf

The p-value returned is given as a range.
I don't want this.  I want and need the exact p-value.

How do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

The range is given due to the use of a critical values table in the background. You can easily find the exact test statistic, but not the associated p-value, because it is not calculated.

It is common to report something like p<.1, due to the extensive use of critical values tables in the past.

If you really want to obtain a more exact p-value, you could try something like the bootstrap.

Comment: Actually, the "statistic" is a modified statistic, based on an *approximation* of the actual distributional test statistic according to Stephens 1970 that is referenced in the program documentation. While the distribution under the null isn't easily obtained for the approximation, the tests at common alpha nominal levels are well controlled, consistent, and reasonably powerful.

Comment: @AdamO: For the uniform distribution it's a simple null, isn't it? So you can just get the distribution of the approximate statistic for a given sample size by simulation. (Same for the actual statistic if you can calculate it.)

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Agree, the 1970s had much different considerations for computational firepower, and yet the package authors have chosen to implement the approximal procedures as if the same considerations apply today. Of course, a simulation-based test approach is an exact test whereas the KS test and Von Mises test has an asymptotic distribution based on a brownian bridge of the empirical process of the inverse quantile... a non-trivial quantity.